# can not process data in HVSRInv

Tags: geo, inverted-index

please help me with this one data, so I want to process my data by entering it into the hvsr modeling format then into the inverse hvsr but the data can only appear graphical values ​​in the inverse only, what should I do if I want to process the data below for HVSRInv?

i have already entered data, but in the modelling format it can not, only the HVSRInv can, and only the graph appears